# Get Category ID from URL title of URL segment?

Tags: categories, entries, related

My Url: http://somelink.com/package/view/a-hald-day-trip-to-the-zoo

//my code below... from url above i want to use entry title category id as my category id below, the url above and my code below have below to separate  channels but they share categories groups//

```
    {exp:channel:entries 
        channel="departures" 
        category="{last_segment_category_id}" 
        limit="10" 
        dynamic="no"
    }
       <p>{title}</p> 
   {/exp:channel:entries}
```

//But this code above Does not work!, i tried using cat2seg but i think this works with category url and not url title//

Answer (score 1):

`{last_segment_category_id}` is not a variable provided directly by ExpressionEngine.  So to get this value you need to install an add-on - it is not clear from your question what add-ons you are using (or what version of EE...).

To get a value from the variable `{last_segment_category_id}` you will need to have installed either **URL Helper** addon (from [here](https://github.com/litzinger/URL-Helper)) or **Low Seg2Cat** (from [here](https://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat/docs)), both of which define this variable.

It is probably worth checking which of these you are using (or install one).  I am not sure what happens to the variable if you install both add-ons...

You also could achieve something like this result using **cat2** ([here](https://github.com/croxton/cat2)) but with different tag syntax.

HTH.

Comment: Ok, sice both Seg2cat and URL Helper are used to find category id from url category segments, they didn't work for getting Entry Url tille segment, so i found a solution using [Title Cat Add-on](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/title-cat)  although its for EE2 i had to twix to work on EE5